# Merge multiple accounts using @react-native-firebase/auth

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

In Firebase Ive set "One account per email address" to true.

This means that when a user has already created a Firebase account using Google sign in....and then they try and also register with Facebook (same email address) then I catch the error with `error.code === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential'`.  
Alternatively If they try to register using email/password I catch with `err.code.toString() === 'auth/email-already-in-use'`

Right now I just alert and tell them an account already exists with that email....however I want to link the accounts together instead.
There is so much conflicting info on line about how to do this.....and the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking#link-federated-auth-provider-credentials-to-a-user-account) on linking accounts does not appear to work for @react-native-firebase. 
code below....once I catch the error I want to know what code I can use to link accounts

```
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

export const signUpUserWithEmail = (email, password) => {
  auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(user => {
      console.log(User created in firebase);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      if (err.code.toString() === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
        Alert.alert(
          'Email already registered',
          'You have already created an account using that email.  You have used either Google, Facebook, or email/password as credentials',
        );
      } 


export const _facebookSignin = async () => {
  try {
    // Attempt login with permissions
    const result = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions([
      'public_profile',
      'email',
    ]);

    const data = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

    const firebaseCredential = await auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(
      data.accessToken,
    );

    const fbUserObj = await auth().signInWithCredential(firebaseCredential);

  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential') {
      Alert.alert(
        'Email already registered',
        'You have already created an account using that email.  You have used either Google, Facebook, or email/password as credentials',
      );
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: I have not - will be looking for someone on Codementor to help.  Once I get solution Ill post